# Difference between utc time zone and device timezone in swift

Tags: swift3

I am working on a chat app. I want to determine the time difference between UTC time zone and device current time zone. How to do that in swift3 ?

Answer (score 11):

```
 // Returns a Date initialized to the current date and time
 let currentDate = Date()

 // Returns the time zone currently used by the system
 let timeZone = NSTimeZone.system

 // Returns the difference in seconds between the receiver and Greenwich Mean Time at a given date.
 let timeZoneOffset = timeZone.secondsFromGMT(for: currentDate) / 3600

 print(timeZoneOffset, "hours offset for timezone", timeZone)

 // example output for Denver (considers daylight saving time)
 // -6  hours offset for timezone  America/Denver (current)
```